# r density function of convolution of exponentially distributed r.v. sometimes produces wrong values

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate a plot in figure 3.4 in "Coalescent Theory: An introduction" by John Wakely. It consists of the density function of "T total", which I will not define further.

**My problem is** that I cant seem to correctly write a function for the distribution function.

The distribution function should be a standard convolution of (n-1) random exponentially distributed variables, where the rate of the i'th r.v. is (i/2). The basic distribution can be written as:

[image]

I think I have coded this correctly:

```
DistExpConv <- function(lambdas, t) {
  product = function(vector, entrance) {
    sapply(entrance, function(x){prod(vector[-x] / (vector[-x] - vector[x]))})
  }

  sapply(t, function(y){
    sum(sapply(lambdas, function(x){
      x * exp(-x * y) * product(lambdas, which(lambdas == x))
    }))
  })
}
```

I think this should give the correct response, at least I cannot see, where it should be wrong. I have then implemented the distribution of T total:

```
T_totaldist <- function(n, t) {
  lambdas = sapply(2:n, function(x){ (x-1)/2 })
  DistExpConv(lambdas , t)
}
```

As seen, this function just forms n-1 lambdas and then sends them into `DistExpConv`.

**So far so good**. My problem arises when trying to plot `T_totaldist` for n = 100 using the curve function:

```
n = c(2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100)
col = rainbow(length(n))
for(i in 1:length(n)){
  curve(T_totaldist(n = n[i], x), 0, 14, col = col[i], add = i!=1)
}
legend(8,0.5,paste("n = ",n, sep = ""), col=col, lty=1)
```

The (in this case pink) curve produced by n = 100 jumps in and out into the extreme negatives and positives. Thus I must conclude my previous functions are doing something wrong. The weird thing is, that the curves of the other n's look perfectly as they should, and from t >= 2 the pink curve is also correct. So I think I might be producing some error for small values of t?
I have no idea how to proceed in making the plot pretty.

[image: Plot of the distributions of T total for different n]

I can see in the x- and y-values of the curve, that e.g. `T_totaldist(100, 0.14)` outputs 4.252961e+13 while `T_totaldist(100, 0.28)` outputs -4.982278e+10. This is clearly not what I want, since the density should be very close to zero at these small values for t, and since the density should never be negative.